# Sum, multiplication, division of functions with different degree of differentiability.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Sorry for the strange title: I was wondering if the following statement is true, not true, and in the latter case what kind of counterexamples you could bring.

Given $f\in C^k$ and $g\in C^h$, then $f+g,\, fg \in C^{min(h,k)}$.

My process behind is the following: We know that adding, multiplying and composing continuous functions result in continuous functions, and from the derivations rules:

$d(fg)_x = df_xg+fdg_x$

$d(f+g)_x = df_x +dg_x$

$d(f\circ g)_x = (df\circ g)_x dg_x$

Then, all the possible $d^{(n)}f_x$ are combinations of other $d^{(m)}f_x$ with $m\leq n$, so as long as all of the $d^{(m)}f_x$ are continuous then also $d^{(n)}f_x$ should be, hence $f\in C^n$.

I realise that for the composition this might not work since by composing with $g$ we might get out of the domain of continuity of $df$ (while i don't think we have domain issues with addition and multiplication, that's why i did not specify it).

But does the statement above hold in general? I highly doubt it but i can't come up with any counterexample for the addition and the multiplication.

(for the composition i found that the function $ln(2-x)\vert ln(x)\vert$ is $C^1((0,2))$ but has the modulus which is $C^0$.)

In case everything i wrote is wrong, is there some relaxed result of the above? What hypotesis am i disregarding that would make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "get out of the domain of continuity of $\mathrm df$"? After all $\mathrm df\in C^{k-1}$

Comment: What is the question? Clearly $C^k$ is a subspace and $C^{k+1} \subset C^k$ so the $\min$ statement must hold.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what i was trying to say was that i believe it is not true in general that $df \in C^{k-1}(g(Dom_f))$ for any $g$ define on the Domain of $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat First of all i wanted to make sure, then i was wondering if there was any similar result regarding the composition as well.

Comment: Of course, if $f,g$ are $C^k$ then so is $f \circ g$, exactly the same idea.